# Problema ao tentar vincular bd ao index

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Criei um arquivo html apenas para aprender um pouco. Também criei um css. Só que, ao tentar vincular um banco de dados para que consiga realizar um cadastro com e-mail e senha no site, não consegui fazer, pois sempre retorna um erro.
Esse é o arquivo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gestão em O.B</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blz.css"> <!direcionamento para o arquivo css>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="formato" action="recebe.php" method="post"> <!formato da tela de login>

        <div class="telalogin"> <!tela de login>
            <img src="shen.jpg" width=150px height=150px> <!imagem>
            <h2 class="titulo"> Acesso ao Sistema </h2> <!titulo>
            <h3 class="subtitulo">Gestão para Operações Binárias</h3> <!subtitulo>

        <div class="email"> <!classe email>
            <label>Email</label> <!legenda do formulário e-mail>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" required></input> <!local para colocar o e-mail>
        </div>

        <div class="senha"> <!classe senha>
            <label>Senha</label> <!legenda do formulario senha>
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha" required></input> <!local para colocar a senha>
        </div>

        <div class="mantersessao"> <!classe do botão de manter sessao ativa>
            <input type="checkbox"></input> <!caixa de marcacao lembre-me>
            <label>Lembre-me</label> <!legenda da caixa lembre-me>
        </div>

        <div class="botao">
            <button type="submit">ACESSAR</button>
        </div>


        </div> <!final da tela inicial>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse é o arquivo que recebe os dados do index.html:

```
<?php

require_once("connection/conexao.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (`email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$email', '$senha',)";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

if(!$result) {
    echo("Ocorreu um erro durante a inserção na tabela!");
} else {
    echo("Dados inseridos com sucesso!");
}

?>
```

Esse é o arquivo de conexão com o PHPMYADMIN:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db("gestao_ob", $con);

if(!$con) {
    die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados; " . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Sou iniciante nessa parte, fiquei a tarde toda tentando, mas não consegui.

O erro é o seguinte:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\Users\-\Desktop\xamp\htdocs\csti\connection\conexao.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\-\Desktop\xamp\htdocs\csti\recebe.php on line 10
Ocorreu um erro durante a inserção na tabela!
```

Comment: Você está passando os parâmetros na ordem errada. O correto seria `mysqli_select_db($con, nome_do_banco)`.

Comment: Olá. Obrigado por responder. Realizei essa correção, agora ficou apenas o seguinte erro no arquivo recebe.php:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\-\Desktop\xamp\htdocs\csti\recebe.php on line 10
Ocorreu um erro durante a inserção na tabela!

a linha 10 é essa:
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

Comment: Você precisa passar 2 parametros para a funcao mysqli_query. Um seria a conexao e o outro a Query. Amigo sugiro q leia a documentacao de cada método e tente pelo menos entender a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Realmente amigo, havia ouvido falar disso. Coloquei o 2° parâmetro e agora o erro parou. Só informa Ocorreu um erro durante a inserção na tabela!. Vou tentar resolver esse erro!

Comment: Remove a virgula no final da sua query de insert, logo apos a variavel senha.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (`email`, `senha`) VALUES ('$email', '$senha')";

Comment: Valeu irmão, agora funcionou. Talvez em uma das tentativas eu esqueci essa vírgula aí. Muito obrigado mesmo! Tentei a tarde toda, e você me salvou kkkkkk. Vaaleeeeeeeeu